# Store splitted string in array

Tags: c, strtok, atoi

I using strtok() to split a string and store in an array like following below

```
char *table[5];
char buffer[50] = {"1-Study"};         // The value is example, get new value by user
char *number;
char *name;
uint8_t tableNumber;

number = strtok(buffer, "-");                 //equals "1"
name = strtok(NULL, "-");                     //equals "Study"

tableNumber = atoi(number);                   //convert char to int

table[tableNumber] = name;

for (c = 0; c < 5; c++)
{
   printf("table %d = %s\n", c, table[c]);
}
```

after get input for 5 times the result should be:

```
table 0 = Study
table 1 = Sleep
table 2 = Party
table 3 = Hello
table 4 = Exit
```

But the resualt is:

```
table 0 = Exit
table 1 = Exit
table 2 = Exit
table 3 = Exit
table 4 = Exit
```

whats the problem?

please help me?

Thanks

---

complete code:

```
char gMessageBuffer[40];
char *gSceneTable[13];

boolean emberAfPreMessageReceivedCallback(EmberAfIncomingMessage* incomingMessage)
{
    if (incomingMessage->apsFrame->profileId == HA_PROFILE_ID)
    {
        if (incomingMessage->apsFrame->clusterId == ZCL_SCENES_CLUSTER_ID)
        {
            MEMCOPY(gMessageBuffer, incomingMessage->message, incomingMessage->msgLen);   // Get incoming message
            gMessageBuffer[incomingMessage->msgLen] = '\0';
            emberEventControlSetDelayMS(getScenePayloadEventControl, SCENE_ACTION_TRESH);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void getScenePayloadEventFunction(void)
{
    char *sceneNumber;
    char *sceneName;
    char *sceneID;
    char *sceneAction;
    uint8_t sceneTableNumber;

    emberAfCorePrintln("///Incoming Message: %s///", gMessageBuffer);

    sceneNumber = strtok(gMessageBuffer, ".");
    sceneName = strtok(NULL, ".");
    sceneID = strtok(NULL, ".");
    sceneAction = strtok(NULL, ".");

    emberAfCorePrintln("///SCENE NUMBER: %s///", sceneNumber);
    emberAfCorePrintln("///SCENE NAME: %s///", sceneName);
    emberAfCorePrintln("///SCENE ID: %s///", sceneID);
    emberAfCorePrintln("///SCENE ACTION: %s///", sceneAction);

    if (strcmp(sceneAction, "Update") == 0)
    {
        sceneTableNumber = atoi(sceneNumber);

        gSceneTable[sceneTableNumber] = strdup(sceneName);
    }
    emberEventControlSetInactive(getScenePayloadEventControl);
}
```

this is for microcontroller in simplicity studio IDE.

I get payload in emberAfPreMessageReceivedCallback correctly
and I split it into 4 parts and print correctly too.

But after copy the sceneName to gSceneTable array I see the last sceneName in all the elements of gSceneTable with gSceneTable[sceneTableNumber] = sceneName and I see "p]" with gSceneTable[sceneTableNumber] = strdup(sceneName);

Comment: Could you provide a complete (compileable) minimal example?

Comment: `char buffer[50] = {"1-Study"};`  --> `char buffer[50] = "1-Study";`

Comment: @David Ranieri: That is the more usual way of doing it, but both are equivalent

Comment: @xanoetux, yeah, is not a problem, but is kinda strange to see multidimensional notation in a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that your program produce the posted output. The code fragment only handles a single string and `char *table[5];` is uninitialized, so printing the strings from `table[0]`, `table[2]`, `table[3]` and `table[4]` has undefined behavior. You specified that the strings are read from a file, posting a complete program is required for a precise and correct analysis. Not initializing the array is a problem in case the file does not have all entries covered, it would be impossible to tell which were set and which weren't.

Assuming your program reads the strings from a file or standard input, parsing them with `strtok` returns pointers to the source string, which is the array into which you read the lines from the file. Hence all entries in the `table[]` array point to the same byte in this array, which explains the output you get: 5 times the contents of the last line.

You should make a copy of the string you store in the table:

```
table[tableNumber] = strdup(name);
```

Here is a completed and modified program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *table[5] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
    char buffer[50];
    char *number;
    char *name;
    int tableNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
            break;
        number = strtok(buffer, "-");
        if (number == NULL) {
            printf("empty line\n");
            continue;
        }
        name = strtok(NULL, "-\n");
        if (name == NULL) {
            printf("no name after -\n");
            continue;
        }
        tableNumber = atoi(number);
        if (tableNumber < 0 || tableNumber >= 5) {
            printf("invalid number: %d\n", tableNumber);
            continue;
        }
        table[tableNumber] = strdup(name);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (table[i])
            printf("table %d = %s\n", i, table[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        free(table[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If your target system does not support `strdup()`, use this:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *mystrdup(const char *s) {
    size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *p = malloc(size);
    return (p != NULL) ? memcpy(p, s, size) : NULL;
}
```

Comment: I use table[tableNumber] = strdup(name); but it don't works anr print p[

Comment: @Majid: post the complete code at the end of your question after an **EDIT:** paragraph.

Comment: @Majid: did you include `<string.h>`?

Comment: @Majid: there is something wrong with your `strdup()`. What system does the code run on?

Comment: in Simplicity studio IDE, and IAR compiler, in windows 10

Comment: Windows 10 hosts your IDE, IAR is typically used for embedded software development. Does your code execute on an external board? There is something fishy with the `strdup()` function on that system. Try using a custom version as posted in my amended answer.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to split gMessageBuffer ?

Comment: @Majid: did you use the custom function `mustrdup()` ? Do you get the same output? Can you post the complete output of you program and the input file (in text form)?

Answer (score -1):

The sample code:

Enter message like "sceneNumber.sceneName.sceneID.Update"

For example: 1.Study.12345.Update

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

char *gSceneTable[13];
char gMessageBuffer[50];

int main()
{
   char *sceneNumber;
   char *sceneName;
   char *sceneID;
   char *sceneAction;
   int sceneTableNumber;
   int check;
   int c;

   printf("Enter payload for 3 Times\r\n");

   while(check != 3)
   {
       scanf("%s", &gMessageBuffer);

       printf("Message is: %s\r\n",gMessageBuffer);

       sceneNumber = strtok(gMessageBuffer, ".");
       sceneName = strtok(NULL, ".");
       sceneID = strtok(NULL, ".");
       sceneAction = strtok(NULL, ".");

       printf("%s\r\n", sceneNumber);
       printf("%s\r\n", sceneName);
       printf("%s\r\n", sceneID);
       printf("%s\r\n", sceneAction);

       if (strcmp(sceneAction, "Update") == 0)
       {
        sceneTableNumber = atoi(sceneNumber);
        gSceneTable[sceneTableNumber] = sceneName;
       }

   check++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)    
   {
       printf("Scene Table: %d ----- %s \r\n", c, gSceneTable[c]);
   }

return 0;
```

}